# RdotNet error: The R engine is not in a working state

Tags: r.net

I am trying to use R-3.2.2 with RdotNet 1.6.5 embedded in a C# application.

I have started getting errors of the type:

*Error  at `RDotNet.REngine.get_LastErrorMessage()`

 at `RDotNet.REngine.Parse(String statement, StringBuilder incompleteStatement)`

 at `RDotNet.REngine.<Defer>d__0.MoveNext()`

 at `System.Linq.Enumerable.LastOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable'1 source)`

 at `RDotNet.REngine.Evaluate(String statement)`

System.Exception: Execution Failed with the following Errors:*
Unable to retrieve an R error message. Evaluating 'geterrmessage()' fails. The R engine is not in a working state.*

Once I get this error, cannot use R without restarting the application.  Sometime even that doesn't work.

Has anyone else seen this error?
A related question, are there any Windows VC++ runtime version requirements for RDotNet 1.6.5?

Comment: R.NET does not require any VC++ runtime. It is written in C# and uses .NET's P/Invoke to call exported C functions in the R API.

Comment: Is this happening in a context where you are using ASP.NET, or a multi-threaded operations? these are the most likely known contexts where this arises.

Comment: It's used in a standard C# application.  I have also ensured that only one thread gets control of REngine at any given time.   Here's what I observed.

Comment: My observations:  On a clean setup, the first time REngine gets used, (Say, run a computation on 100 items) everything works fine.  Once that computation is complete, if I run the same computation on the next set of 100 items, I get this error.   So, I reviewed the clean-up code that I execute at the end of each pass - I execute `rm(list=ls())` to flush all the R objects.  Not executing that command may have fixed the issue - still testing it out.  Does this sound like a plausible cause?